# Can someone explain to me the grammatical structure of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, nuances

> うん、少々偏ってるくらいでどうにかなっちゃうものじゃないから

The whole sentence means a little 偏って doesn't matter but why does じゃないから not acting as a negation for どうにかなっちゃうもの

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing two (almost) opposite meaning of どうにかなる.

どうにかなる can mean both *to work out, go through somehow* and *to get cracked, break*. The former means "things stay okay" whereas the latter means "something will go wrong with the subject".

For examples,

- お金がなくてもどうにかなる - I can manage/work out things even if I have no money.
- 寒すぎてどうにかなってしまいそうだ - It's too cold and I'm going crazy/to break.

The sentence uses どうにかなっちゃう in the 'go wrong' sense and I think you understand it as 'work out' sense. The じゃない is simply a negation - so どうにかなっちゃうものじゃない means *(it) won't break*.

Comment: Ohh, I see. So, my understanding is correct, but I lack the information on the other meaning of どうにかなる.
By the way, how did you know about that other meaning. Every dictionary I looked at, どうにかなる always has the positive meaning.

Comment: @Cometto I'm a native speaker, so there's no *how* for me, but it is a good question since monolingual dictionaries do not mention this explicitly, either. One source could be [英辞郎](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b).

Comment: It gives three results : もうちょっとどうにかなるのではないか could use a little help〔控えめな言い方。〕/精神的にどうにかなる have a mental meltdown / 頭がどうにかなる
have a mental meltdown（主語の). The last two are 'go wrong' sense.

Comment: Thanks, I finally understand now